# convert flattened data to nested hierarchy

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a flattened data structure (which is actually a result from a DB SQL Query so there will be a lot of duplicate data) and I would like to convert this to a heirarchy.

Input structure:

```
class Data {
    int key1;
    String value1;
    int key2;
    Integer key3;
    String finalValue;
}
```

Output structure

```
class Struct1 {
    int key1;
    String value1;
    List<Struct2> inner;
}

class Struct2 {
    int key2;
    List<Struct3> inner;
}

class Struct3 {
    int key3;
    String finalValue;
}
```

so.....

```
 List<Data> input = ....
 List<Struct1> results = input.stream().collect(groupingBy(x->x.key1, .....);
```

The tools at my disposal are group/map/reduce but I can't work out the correct combination/nesting to achieve my desired result.

p.s. just to make this interesting. This is an outer join query to the database so there might not be any Struct3 elements for a Struct2 (hence why key3 is an Integer and not at int)

example data:

```
key1     value1     key2     key3     finalValue
1        "value1"   2        3        "final1"
1        "value1"   2        4        "final2"
1        "value1"   3        null     null
5        "value2"   6        7        "final3"
```

I expect a result something like the following

```
[{
   "key1" : 1,
   "value1" : "value1",
   "inner" : [ {
           "key2" : 2,
           "inner" : [ {
                "key3" : 3,
                "finalValue" : "final1"
               }, {
                "key3" : 4,
                 "finalValue" : "final2"
               }],
            }, {
           "key2" : 3,
           "inner" : []
         }],
}, {
    "key1" : 5,
    "value1" : "value2",
    "inner" : [ {
           "key2" : 6,
           "inner" : [ {
                "key3" : 7,
                "finalValue" : "final3"
            }]
}]
```

Here is an answer, but I am not a big fan:

```
Map<Long, Data> groupByKey1 = data.stream().collect(groupingBy(x->x.key1));
List<Struct1> result = groupByKey1.entrySet().stream().map(this::createStruct1).collect(toList());

Struct1 createStruct1(Entry<Long, List<Data>> item) {
    List<Struct2> struct2 = item.getValue().stream().collect(groupingBy(x->x.key2)).entrySet().stream().map(this::createStruct2).collect(toList());
    // create and return Struct1
    .....
 }
```

2nd attempt (which I think is the answer I am looking for)

```
Map<Long, Data> groupByKey1 = data.stream().collect(groupingBy(x->x.key1, collectingAndThen(toList(), this::createStruct1));

Struct1 createStruct1(List<Data> item) {
List<Struct2> struct2 = item.stream().collect(groupingBy(x->x.key2, collectingAndThen(toList(), this::createStruct2));
// create and return Struct1
.....
```

}

Thanks in advance

Stu

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor in class `Struct1` that takes all values for one row, write similar constructors for the other classes and call them from the `Struct1` constructor. Once that is done, writing a correct stream should be easy.

```
public Struct1(int key1, String value1, int key2, Integer key3, String finalValue) {
   this.key1 = key1;
   this.value1 = value1;

   Struct3 str3 = new Struct3(key3, finalValue);
   Struct2 str2 = new Struct2(key2, str3);

   this.inner = new ArrayList<>();
   this.inner.add(str2);
}
```

---

Here is an example handling both creating and updating Struct1 objects. Old school for loop though.

```
Map<Integer, Struct1> cache = new HashMap<>();
for (Data data: input) {
    Struct1 str1 = cache.get(data.key1);
    if (str1 == null) {
        str1 = new Struct1(data.key1, data.value1, data.key2, data.key3, data.finalValue);
        cache.put(str1.key1, str1);
     } else {
        str1.update(data.key2, data.key3, data.finalValue);
     }
 }

 List<Struct1> result = cache.values();
```

Comment: This will only ever provide we with one instance of Struct2 inside Struct1, In the example data there are 2 elements inside Struct2. It is a one-many relattionship between Struct1 and the same between Struct2 and Struct3.
If I was to follow your proposal then Struct2 constructor would require a collection of Struct3 items and Struct1 would require a collection of Struct2 items

Comment: Then add each created Struct1 object to a dictionary with key1 as the key and complement Struct1 (and Struct2) with an update method. This might be easier to handle in a traditional loop rather than using streams.